# Swift Pinterest Layout add header

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, pinterest

I'm using a `collectionView` with the library `PinterestLayout`. When I create my own `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, I just have to add the `.headerRefenceSize`and these 2 methods:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView`

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize
```

With this, I have my header. Now I changed the `PinterestLayout` heritance from `UICollectionViewLayout` to `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and added, inside the method: `prepare` the following line:

`self.headerReferenceSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 75)`

But still, no header showing. Can anyone tell me how to add a header inside `PinterestLayout`.

I need to keep the same cell picture ratio that `PinterestLayout` gives for my collectionView.

Answer (score -3):

Solved. I did manage to change the PinterestLayout library to create a header inside. Might update the answer if people are in need for the solution.

Comment: Users have asked for the solution (sadly they did so in answers which are not answers because of not having the comment privilege). If you have a solution, please provide it.